# R: basemap of San Francisco

Tags: r, geospatial, geocoding

What R packages are needed to get basemap of San Francisco with all street outlines?

What is the R code to create that basemap?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `leaflet` package for that:

```
library(leaflet)
  leaflet() %>%
  addTiles() %>% setView(lat=37.7793,lng=-122.41899999999998,zoom=8)
```